# How should I prevent HTML from interpreting user-entered text as an entity?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website where users and enter text.  A user entered something "I worked on the #3&#4 valves" into an `<input>`.  That text gets stored in a database, and displayed on screen somewhere else.  My problem is that the "&#4" is being interpreted as an HTML entity or special character, and I want it to be interpreted literally.

Do I need to use Javascript to escape `&` from the `<input>`?  I was hoping that `<pre>` would work, but it also interprets the text as a code.  Again, this is user inputted text.

For example, when I run the code below, the `<input>` shows different text than the `<p>`.  I want the `<p>` to show exactly what the `<input>` shows.

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="box">
<p id="para"></p>
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById("box").value = "something #3&#4";
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "something #3&#4";
</script>
</html>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9746ah8s/)**

**EDIT:**

I realized that I'll need both a client-side solution and a server-side solution.  In one place that user-inputted text is displayed, I'm using Javascript's `.innerHTML`, and on another webpage, I'm `echo`ing it with PHP.

Comment: What is your server side langage ?

Comment: PHP. Just added an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your real issue is a lack of server side filtering.  Given that you are having this problem, it seems very likely to me that you aren't doing any server-side input filtering/cleaning at all, which means that you are also going to be vulnerable to [XSS](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cross-Site-Scripting-(XSS).html)

On the server side you should be sanitizing everything that goes back out to the client, which includes both stripping HTML tags (and also returning errors on save if people try to send up HTML tags) as well as replacing html special characters (see [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)).  The latter will convert your `&` into `&amp;`, which will have the end result you desire: your HTML will not be interpreted as HTML special characters.

The problem with fixing this with javascript client side is that, not only do you have to do it everywhere, but you also have to remember to do it in a different way if there are cases where this same output is shown in the HTML document itself, i.e. not displayed by javascript.

In short, coming up with a coherent (and thorough) method for sanitizing user data before it goes back to the browser will fix your problem and also provide a first layer of protection against a number of malicious attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I thought I was safe by using prepared statements, but I guess that's not enough.  Thankfully, this is an intranet site, but I'll look into protecting against XSS.

Comment: XSS vulnerable intranet sites? Yes please! It's easy to think security is less important in areas with restricted user access (i.e. intranet sites): I've thought that myself sometimes.  The reality though is that these areas are often more valuable to attackers.  You won't be vulnerable to drive-by-attacks, but you will be more vulnerable to people specifically interested in your company, and also disgruntled employees.  The level of security should always be determined by the value of the thing you are protecting: whether or not the system itself is publicly accessible doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9746ah8s/3/)**.

Try to append the content as text not as HTML using one of the followinf methods ( **[`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)** or **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** ), like :

```
document.getElementById("para").innerText = "something #3&#4";
document.getElementById("para").textContent = "something #3&#4";
```

**NOTE :** In case of server-side display you could use `htmlentities($content)`.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.getElementById("para").textContent = "something #3&#4";
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop manipulating it as HTML, because text only becomes code if you do it explicitly. In a slightly modified version of your example, please compare:

```js
var txt = "one <strong>two</strong>";
document.getElementById("box").value = txt;
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = txt;
document.getElementById("para2").innerText = txt;
```

```html
<input id="box">
<p id="para1"></p>
<p id="para2"></p>
```

(In the case of `<input>` there's only one option because the element cannot hold HTML in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9746ah8s/2/

Answer (score -2):

To display &, you could replace all the & with &amp, this way you will see #3&#4 and '&#4' wont be interpreted.

Comment: This is user inputted text. I can't tell all my users to type `&amp` instead of `&`.

Comment: A simple replace will do the work, `"something #3&#4".replace("&", "&amp")`

Comment: `&` is not the only character with special meaning in HTML